# How do I make a Vuejs value display in my html?

Tags: vue.js

How do I make the name 'John' display on the webpage. It is displaying '{{firstName}}' rather than John.

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{firstName}} </h1>',
     data() {
        return {
            firsName: 'John',
        }
    },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: You have a typo. In your template you are using `firstName` where as in data it's `firsName`(Without `t`)

Comment: Thanks Abdul, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

syntax mistake in firstName, try this:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{firstName}} </h1>',
     data() {
        return {
            firstName: 'John',
        }
    },
})

app.mount('#app')
```